# How to translate WPCalender WordPress Plugin Form labels using WPML?

Tags: wordpress, wpml

Hi I am translating my site in many languages using WPML Plugin, but there is an issue with the booking form labels of WP Calender, As WP calender supports WPML.
I have to translate the string under `Booking -> Setting -> Form -> Field Label` inside admin panel.

[image]

And this is a front view of my form::
[image]

Help me to translate the form labels Name, Email, Phone Number, Please enter details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPML will add these string inside custom category, these all strings will be inside string translation section with the custom category. Make translation and save the changes.